# Remove characters from string using replace()

Tags: python-3.x, replace

feeling stupid with this one :/

I know I'm using the method wrong in some way, but with only https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace to work with I just can't see why I can't do what I'm trying to achieve here (which I hope is obvious enough?)

```
import string

word2 = 'abc?ef,hi.!l@'

for x in string.punctuation:
    if x in word2:
        word2.replace(x,'')

print (word2)
```

I've tried a few debugs & print statements so I know it's iterating through string.substring OK, and I know it's going through word2 and recognising when each x is present, but why isn't replace() actually doing anything here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import string

word2 = "abc?ef,hi.!l@"

for x in string.punctuation:
    if x in word2:      //works with or without
        word2 = word2.replace(x,"")// save the after replace is done.
print(word2)
```

output:

> abcefhil

Comment: I might add that you don't really need the conditional `if x is in word2`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yea true

Comment: Thanks. It was actually the fact you have to assign to a variable what replace() produces that I was missing/didn't understand. @juanpa.arrivillaga Wow, didn't realise that either but seems obvious now. Thanks.

Comment: @Phlebas_The_Seabass you welcome, you can accept the accept the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join` and comprehension to do this in one straightforward line.

```
import string

word2 = "abc?ef,hi.!1@"
word2 = ''.join(c for c in word2 if c not in punctuation)
```